# Why doesn't PrintServer.GetPrintQueues get the correct PrintTicket while PrintServer.GetPrintQueue does?

Tags: .net, wpf, printing

When I try to get all the printers and iterate through them with :

```
        Dim printServer As New PrintServer()         
        For Each printer As PrintQueue In printServer.GetPrintQueues({EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local, EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections})
            ...
        Next
```

It looks like it's working fine only the UserPrintTicket for the returned printers is incorrect. If I set a printer in landscape mode in the printer settings and use this method, my printer.UserPrintTicket is still in portrait mode.

BUT (and that's the catch) if I do :

```
        printServer.GetPrintQueue(printerName)
```

Then my UserPrintTicket is correct. I would use this only I can't seem to find how to access network printers with this function (and I tried several ways to get it, no luck).

So here's my two questions :

1. Why on earth are the UserPrintTicket different between two seemingly identical methods?
2. How can I get network printers with GetPrintQueue?

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but to use `GetPrintQueue` with a networkprinter pass the `.Description` of the printer instead of `.FullName` don't ask me why it is this way but it seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I tried to solve this issue most of the day yesterday and this morning I finally found the solution. I still don't know why 1) UserPrintTicket is different between GetPrintQueues and GetPrintQueue, but to list all of my printers and get the correct UserPrintTicket for each one you need to call GetPrintQueue on the printer's HostingPrintServer for it to work. So in other words :

```
        Dim printServer As New PrintServer()

        For Each printer As PrintQueue In printServer.GetPrintQueues({EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local, EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections})
              'Get the parent PrintServer and uses it to get the PrintQueue, seems like overkill but that's the only way I found to get the correct UserPrintTicket    
              Dim currentPrinter As PrintQueue = printer.HostingPrintServer.GetPrintQueue(printer.Name)
              ...
        Next
```

Hope that helps someone!